# MongoDB query: how to select the longest period of time of a matched value

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime

I have a mongo database with many records in the format of:

```
{
  id: {
    $_id
  },
  date: {
    $date: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
  },
  reading: X.XX
}
```

where the date is a timestamp in mongo and reading is a float *(id is just the unique identifier for the data point)* .

I would like to be able to count the longest period of time when the reading was a certain value *(lets say 0.00 for ease of use)* and return the start and end points of this time period.  If there were more than one time period of the same length I would like them all returned.

Ultimately, for example, I would like to be able to say

"The longest time period the reading is `0.00` and `1.25 hours`

between

`2000-01-01T00:00:00 - 2000-01-01T01:15:00`,

`2000-06-01T02:00:00 - 2000-06-01T03:15:00`,

`2000-11-11T20:00:00 - 2000-11-11T21:15:00` ."

For my mongo aggregation query I am thinking of doing this:

1. get the timeframe I am interested in *(eg `2000-01-01 to
   2001-01-01`)*
2. sort the data by date descending
3. somehow select the longest run when the reading is `0.00`.

This is the query I have so far:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
    date: { $gte: ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.0Z") }
    }
  },
  { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
  {
    "$group" : {
      "_id": null,
      "Maximum": { "$max": { "max": "$reading", "date": "$date" } },
      "Longest": { XXX: { start_dates: [], end_dates: [] } }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "max": "$Maximum",
      "longest": "$Longest"
    }
  }
]
```

I do not know how to select the longest run.  How would you do this?

*(You will notice I am also interested in the maximum reading within the time period and the dates on which that maximum reading happens.  At the moment I am only recording the latest date/time this occurs but would like it to record all the dates/times the maximum value occurs on eventually.)*

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Pleas add a example and your expected output

Comment: My expected output would be an array containing the longest number of hours that the reading was 0.00 and the start date(s) and end date(s) when that time frame occurred.

Comment: use an [arithmetic aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) on the data's and sort descending. The value you want would be the first value. `$subtract`

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal - could you please expand on your comment?  I am relatively new to mongo syntax and haven't come across $subtract before.  I am not sure I understand who your proposed answer would get all the dates and times for the start and end points but that is probably because I don't understand not your answer!